# Размен 100 рублей монетами 2, 5 и 10

Tags: java, c++, python, математика, комбинаторика

Здравствуйте.
Как посчитать аналитически число вариантов размена 100 рублей монетами по 10, 5 и 2 рубля? Как выглядит код прямого перебора?

UPD.
Благодарю @Alexander Zonov за код на C.
Вот код на Java:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, j, k, count = 0;
        for (i = 0; i <= 100; i+=2)
            for (j = i; j <= 100; j+=5)
                for (k = j; k <= 100; k+=10)
                    if (k == 100){
                        System.out.printf("%d * 2 + %d * 5 + %d * 10\n", i/2, (j-i)/5, (k-j)/10);
                        count++;
                    }
        System.out.println("Число вариантов равно " + count);
    }
}
```

Вот код на C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    const int SUM = 100;
    int i, j, k, count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= SUM; i+=2)
        for (j = i; j <= SUM; j+=5)
            for (k = j; k <= SUM; k+=10)
                if (k == SUM){
                    count++;
                    printf("%d * 2 + %d * 5 + %d * 10, count %d\n", i/2, (j-i)/5, (k-j)/10, count);
                }       
    printf("Число вариантов размена равно %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

И на Python 3:

```
sum = 100
count = 0
for i in range(0, sum + 1, 2):
    for j in range(i, sum + 1, 5):
        for k in range(j, sum + 1, 10):
            if k == sum:
                count += 1
                print(str(int(i/2)) + "*2", str(int((j-i)/5)) + "*5", str(int((k-j)/10)) + "*10", "вариант №" + str(count))
print("Число вариантов равно " + str(count))
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/616321/177345

Comment: Если вы нашли решение - оформите его в виде ответа (ответить на собственный вопрос), а не пишите решение в вопросе.

Comment: *Как посчитать аналитически* Мне всегда казалось, что посчитать аналитически - это вывести формулу прямого вычисления требуемого значения. Которая в данном случае выглядит как сумма чисел от 1 до 11, т.е. ((100/10+1)+1)*(100/10+1)/2=66.

Comment: @Akina, а какими рассуждениями вы руководствовались?

Comment: @woodhead 2 и 5 взаимно просты и являются делителями 10. Соответственно 10 рублей представимо только как (10), (5,5), (2,2,2,2,2), без интерференций. Для произвольной, не строго круглой, суммы, дополнительно надо обработать остаток от деления на 10, причём для последних цифр 1 или 3 остатком считать 11 и 13 соответственно.

Comment: @Akina увы, но логика от меня ускользает

Answer (score 2):

Тупым перебором примерно так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i <= 100; i+=2)
        for (j = i; j <= 100; j+=5)
            for (k = j; k <= 100; k+=10)
                if (k == 100)
                    printf("%d * 2 + %d * 5 + %d * 10\n", i/2, (j-i)/5, (k-j)/10);
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/4egbO3

Вот тот же "метод тыка", только без фиксированных циклов (в ответ на часть критики в комментариях):

```
int main()
{
    int M = 1000;
    int numbers[] = {17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37};
    int N = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]);
    int values[N], count = 0, i, v;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) values[i] = 0;

    while (1) {
        if ((M - values[0]) % numbers[0] == 0)
            count++;
        for (i = 1; i < N; i++) {
            v = values[i] + numbers[i];
            if (v > M) continue;
            break;
        }
        if (i == N) break;
        while (i >= 0) values[i--] = v;
    }

    printf("count = %d\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/O5OwR7

Comment: Тупой перебор на то и тупой, что его надо избегать.

Comment: @Other а ещё такой вариант абсолютно не приспособлен к разному количеству номиналов монет.

Comment: @Other на практике это единственный полный ответ на поставленный вопрос

Comment: @jfs, вообще-то не полный. Автор еще просил аналитически посчитать.

Comment: Верно. Я имел в виду ответ на вопрос: «как выглядит код прямого перебора»

Comment: вот для тестов [рекурсивный и итеративные варианты на Питоне, чтобы кол-во  посчитать](https://gist.github.com/zed/35366bbe7eae1e14e99f)

Comment: @jfs, спасибо. Классный способ с прибавлением к количеству вариантов собрать сумму количества вариантов собрать сумму минус номинал монеты. Но это, вроде, не совсем прямой перебор, как просил автор вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

Простейший вариант аналитически получается как коэффициент при [image: введите сюда описание изображения] в разложении в степенной ряд

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(см. задачу 7.2.1.4-11 из *Искусства программирования* Кнута, том 4А).

Там же можно найти соответствующие алгоритмы. Замечу только, что для реально больших чисел и большого количества номиналов можно просто не дожить до конца тупого перебора.

Comment: Это смотря сколько жить :)

Comment: @Harry Что обозначает в данном примере z?

Comment: Переменную :) Обозначьте, как хотите. Главное - когда вы разложите приведенную дробь в степенной ряд, коэффициент при z^100 будет искомым значением.

Comment: Перебор до сотни быстрый, динамика ещё быстрее. А твой ответ я вообще не понял. Можно что-нибудь пояснить для тех, кто не читал Кнута?

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну, разложение будет иметь вид произведения (1+z^2+z^4+...)(1+z^5+z^10+...)(1+z^10+z^20+...) - и коэффициент при z^100 и будет той самой величиной. А вот чтоб посчитать его, например, рекурсивно - тут никакого комментария, да и ответа не хватит, тут Кнута нужно...