# Как осуществить перебор всех возможных вариантов выдачи денег банкоматом?

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм, методы

У меня стоит задача: проверить, может ли банкомат выдать указанную сумму, и, если да, то предоставить **все возможные варианты** выдачи денег. Проверку я сделал, но не понимаю алгоритм перебора. На форумах не нашёл нужного объяснения. Нашёл несколько вариантов кода, но мне не понравилась структура, где алгоритм разбит на несколько методов. Мне нужен перебор в одном методе.

```
public class Atm {
    private int numberBanknotes20;
    private int numberBanknotes50;
    private int numberBanknotes100;

    public Atm (int numberBanknotes20, int numberBanknotes50, int numberBanknotes100) {
        this.numberBanknotes20 = numberBanknotes20;
        this.numberBanknotes50 = numberBanknotes50;
        this.numberBanknotes100 = numberBanknotes100;
    }
    public int addBanknotes20(int number) {
        return numberBanknotes20 += number;
    }
    public int addBanknotes50(int number) {
        return numberBanknotes50 += number;
    }
    public int addBanknotes100(int number) {
        return numberBanknotes100 += number;
    }
    public boolean isPossibleIssue(int amount) {
        int amountBanknotes20 = numberBanknotes20;
        int amountBanknotes50 = numberBanknotes50;
        int amountBanknotes100 = numberBanknotes100;
        int banknotes20 = 20;
        int banknotes50 = 50;
        int banknotes100 = 100;
        int amountAllBanknotes = banknotes20 * amountBanknotes20 + banknotes50 * amountBanknotes50
                + banknotes100 * amountBanknotes100;
        boolean check;

        System.out.println("Amount all banknotes: " + amountAllBanknotes + " BYN");
        if (amountAllBanknotes < amount || amount % 10 != 0 || amount == 0) {
            check = false;
        } else {
            while (amount > 0 && amountBanknotes100 > 0) {
                amount -= banknotes100;
                amountBanknotes100--;
            }
            if (amount < 0) {
                amount += banknotes100;
                amountBanknotes100++;
            }
            while (amount > 0 && amountBanknotes50 > 0) {
                amount -= banknotes50;
                amountBanknotes50--;
            }
            if (amount < 0) {
                amount += banknotes50;
                amountBanknotes50++;
            }
            while (amount > 0 && amountBanknotes20 > 0) {
                amount -= banknotes20;
                amountBanknotes20--;
            }
            check = true;
        }
        return check;
    }
```

У меня есть вот такой метод. Тип возвращаемого значения я не знаю, так как не понимаю, делать это через массив или есть другие способы. Мне бы хотелось понять логику перебора. Что, как и каким-образом? Так что объяснение всей схемы очень приветствуется.

```
public getOptionsCombinationBanknotes (int amount) {
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно именно перечисление вариантов, или их общее количество?...

Comment: @Harry перечесление. Потом исходя из выбранного варианта будут выдаваться деньги.

Comment: А вот это вот не смотрели? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/616321/Перебор-всех-возможных-вариантов-размена-суммы-на-маленькие-монеты?rq=1

Comment: @m.vokhm смотрел, вот только проблема в том, что все решения в том ответе кардинально меняют структуру кода. Моя задача состоит, как я писал выше, в написании алгоритма в методе getOptionsCombinationBanknotes, куда просто вводится сумма

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ловите псевдокод. Решаем задачу рекурсивно.

```
function variants(sum, minvalue, valuelist)
   if (sum == 0)
        print(valuelist)
        return 
   if (minvalue >= 100) and (sum >= 100)
        variants(sum - 100, 100, valuelist + [100]) 
   if (minvalue >= 50) and (sum >= 50)
        variants(sum - 50, 50, valuelist + [50]) 
   if (sum >= 20)
        variants(sum - 20, 20, valuelist + [20])
```

Пример выдачи для суммы 200 (`variants(200, 100, [])`)

```
[100, 100]
[100, 50, 50]
[100, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
[50, 50, 50, 50]
[50, 50, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
[20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
```

Если нужно получить факт того, что сумма возможна

```
function variants(sum, minvalue, valuelist)
   if (sum == 0)
        print(valuelist)
        return True
   res = False    
   if (minvalue >= 100) and (sum >= 100)
        res |= variants(sum - 100, 100, valuelist + [100]) 
   if (minvalue >= 50) and (sum >= 50)
        res |= variants(sum - 50, 50, valuelist + [50]) 
   if (sum >= 20)
        res |= variants(sum - 20, 20, valuelist + [20]) 
   return res
```

Comment: А как правильно прописать в Java valuelist + [100] ?

Comment: Если valuelist сделать строкой - то передать модифицированную `valuelist  + " 100"`.  Если  valuelist - ArrayList, то передать модифицированный  ArrayList c добавлением к нему числа. Как грамотно это сделать в java - точно не знаю. Только обратите внимание, что в трёх ветках один и тот же начальный объект должен участвовать, а модифицированные только передаются на следующий уровень

Comment: Данный способ работает, **НО** если брать строки для каждой купюры по отдельности(Например, только 100), то все верно заполняет. Если же открыть все строки с купюрами, то не до конца заполняет. Например, для выдачи 100 выдает вариант "20 20 50", что ровняется 90 и "100 100". По факту, выдает лишние варианты, которые совсем не нужны. Но этот код уже близок к решению. И еще не понимаю, почему для 100 выводит "100 100", ведь на 2 итерацию условие не должно проходить. Не совпадает у меня с вашим выводом. Может я чего-то не понимаю или что-то упустил ?

Comment: Я привёл выдачу [реального кода](https://ideone.com/QQuyiP). Для суммы 100 выдаёт три варианта. А что означает `Если же открыть все строки с купюрами`?

Comment: Я дико извиняюсь, я сейчас совершил ошибку в коде и из-за этого все пошло наперекосяк. У меня вывод работает как надо. Благодарю вас. И последняя просьба, перед тем, как я отмечу ваш вариант решенным, можете ли вы объяснить логику кода ? Я не совсем понимаю, каким образом код зацикливается. Циклов никаких не стоит, но при этом, методы по новой начинают считать. Или я как то не так понимаю ?

Comment: Это [рекурсия](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F). Функция проверяет, не найдено ли решение (денег не осталось). Если да - выводит. Если нет, деньги ещё остались, то функция вызывает себя же с меньшей суммой, доложив возможную купюру в текущий набор.

Comment: Отлично, я понял. Большое спасибо

Comment: `Если да - выводит.` Тут, кстати, нужно сделать выход, чтобы лишние проверки не проводились

Comment: Еще такой вопрос. Без этого условия, код ничего не выдает. Пробовал return ставить вместо print, и все равно не выдает. Только через print и работает, а ведь значение мне надо вернуть.
`if (sum == 0) print(valuelist)`

Comment: Скобки не забыли? `if (sum == 0) {print(valuelist); return}`. А возвращать valuelist не очень хорошо, точнее - его использовать не так просто. Попробую код модифицировать под boolean